# How to get rendered source code of an html page from code behind so I can send it in mail

Tags: asp.net, html

I created an aspx page wit a button send. 
on that button click a function code behind goes on.
What I want is that when I click on the button to get all the **html** source code rendered of the aspx page in a variable so I can send it in a mail. how can I get the rendered html
source code from code behind function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just wrote a method for this not too long ago. It gets the view at a provided relative path, passes in a provided model, and renders the view as a string.

```
public static string RenderViewToString(string relativePathToControl, object viewData)
{
    ViewPage viewPage = new ViewPage() { ViewContext = new ViewContext() };

    viewPage.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(viewData);
    viewPage.Controls.Add(viewPage.LoadControl(relativePathToControl));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            viewPage.RenderControl(tw);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

You may need to add a few using statements.

Comment: I should add that I only used this for partial views (.ascx). I'm not sure how it would work for a .aspx file.

Comment: I suppose this solution works only for MVC, not for WebForms. Am I right?